# Uploading pdf to firebase storage via NodeJS, corrupted file

Tags: node.js, firebase, pdf, upload, storage

I build an admin panel for my firebase app with nodejs.
Now I want to upload a pdf file to firebase/google storage.

My Javascript-client, to upload those files from computer, looks like this:

```
 $("#upload-pdf").on("change", function(e) {
            file = e.target.files[0];

            document.getElementById("pdfName").value = file.name;

            if (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                    var fileContent = reader.result;
                    $('#pdfPreview').attr('src', event.target.result);
                    document.getElementById("pdfContent").value = fileContent;
                }
            }
        });
```

The imagecontent of the file (value of pdfContent) will now be sent to my nodejs server via ajax:

```
 ...
  $.ajax({
                    url: '/editMenucard',           
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(output),
                    contentType: 'application/json',            
                    success: function(data) {
                        window.location.assign('/restaurant/overview');
                    }
                // ...
                }).catch(function(error) {
                // Handle error
                });
```

In my nodejs-server I have implemented the following:

```
    var bucket = admin.storage().bucket('myBucketName');

                const contents = data.PDF.PDFContent;

                mimeType = contents.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/)[1];
                fileName = data.PDF.PDFName + '-original.' + mimeTypes.detectExtension(mimeType);
                base64EncodedPDFString = contents.replace("data:application\/pdf;base64,", '');
                PDFBuffer = new Buffer.from(base64EncodedPDFString, 'base64');


                const file = bucket.file('restaurant-menucards/' + fileName);
                console.log(mimeType);
                file.save(PDFBuffer, {
                    contentType: mimetype + ";charset=utf-8",
                    gzip : false,
                    metadata: { contentType: mimetype + ";charset=utf-8" },
                    public: true,
                    validation: 'md5'
                }, function (error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        console.log("PDF successfully written")
                    }
                });
```

The file is successfully uploaded to my firebase storage, but unforunately, when I want to open it (or embedd it in my html view via signed URL, that I created for) it doesn't work.

The error appears:

```
Fehler
Fehler beim Laden des PDF-Dokuments.
```

In english it means something like "Error; Failed to load pdf document".

So I think my PDF-file is corrupted. I also tested it in Safari, and the pdf didn't appear either.

Is there anything, I do wrong with my upload?
I'm using, as you can see, the NodeJS method "save" from the object "file".

Does anyone have suggestions for me?

I've tried on different browsers and it doesn't work.
The base64 string is not corrupted. I tried it in an online Base64-Converter and the pdf showed correctly.

Comment: I also tried it without escaping but it didn't work either. Also the file base64 isn't corrupted, I tested it in an online base64 converter and the pdf showed fine. I think it has something to do with Chrome or the embedding maybe?

Comment: Hy there @Tobi, I´m facing similar issues while dealing with pdf files in firebase storage. How you dealt with this issues? What npm module you´ve used to get the `data.PDF.PDFContent` call?